# Add Elements to Landing Page Header in Weebly

Tags: weebly

I would like to change the call to action button on the landing page of my website to a social icons element. How do I edit the HTML code to do this? I am using the "Paris - Business" theme. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is some documentation on how to do this, if you search the web. For example, my own site has a basic example of what to look for [Landing Page Button Removal](https://www.jeffreytkastner.com/blog/landing-page-button-removal).

In that case, you could replace the code that makes the button with your own code.

---

That being said, there's some new features you can use that would make the content editable. Weebly just introduced "Sections". Sections allows you to have different sections on a page, and with that you can also drag and drop into the Header area. (See Screenshot)

*BUT, before you go ahead and do this, I should note that Weebly plans on making these changes to the newer themes, in the near future. When Paris would be done, or if it will be done, is anybody's guess.

[image]

Depending on the design of your Theme, this might be slightly different, so please keep that in mind.

Basically, for the Paris Theme, what was:

```
    <div class="banner-wrap wsite-background">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="banner">
                <h2>{headline:text global="false"}</h2>
                <p>{headline-paragraph:text global="false"}</p> 
                <div class="button-wrap">{action:button global="false"}</div>
                <span id="contentArrow"><span></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Would become:

```
<div class="banner-wrap wsite-background">
    <div class="container">
      {{#header}}
        <div class="banner">
            {content}
            <span id="contentArrow"><span></span></span>
        </div>
      {{/header}}
    </div>
</div>
```

*If you are customizing a Theme, I might also recommend making a custom page type, specifically with these changes.

---

If you want to use Sections, for the content area of the page it would look something like:

```
<div class="main-wrap">
  {{#sections}}
      <div class="container">{content}</div>
  {{/sections}}
</div>
```

**Note: There isn't any documentation yet, and I have not tested this, so wsite-background may not be needed... but don't take my word for it.